# Need to persist local date from Json input to oracle DB in a spring-boot application

Tags: java, json, date, date-conversion

I have the local date in json input in String format `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` format [let it be any format no issue], have a separate field timezone in header [eg : CST , CDT etc]. In java when i try to create a date with this value and timezone it is getting created with my system [jvm running system] timezone.

I need to persist the exact date and time from input with the input timezone.
How can I do it ?

I even tried with putting date object with `@DateTimeFormat` in dto instead of string but that did not work.

I want a method like this to get the local date from the input date string and timezone.

```
public Date getLocalDate(String dateString, String localTimeZone) {

  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");   
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(localTimeZone));        
  return formatter.parse(dateString);
}
```

Input :  dateString : "20-04-2019 20:15:00 AM"  localTimeZone : "CDT" .

Expected Output : Date object with value 20-04-2019 20:15:00 AM CDT .

Actual Output   : same date with IST-CDT hour difference with IST timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding about what a `Date` object really is. It is just a number of milliseconds since `'01-01-1970 00:00:00 UTC'`. Said differently it is *always* an UTC date/time and it is implicitely converted in your local time zone by the default formatter when you try to print it.

If you want to store both the *instant* (ie the UTC date/time) and a time zone, you will have to use a `Calendar` object. But anyway, if you want to store both the time and the zone in Oracle, you should directly store a string, or a date and a string (for the timezone), because AFAIK, Oracle DATE fields have no notion of a time zone.

Comment: Ok, if i don't want the zone but just need the exact input date n time. If i simply convert the input string to Date can i get the exact date n time ? There shouldn't be any change in input data and data in DB. Assume i cant change the data type in DB [its  Date itself] . I have to do some business logic as well using this date.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

“CST” and such 2-4 character pseudo-zones are not time zones. They are not standardized and are not even unique! Ex: `CST` is Central time in North America and also China Standard Time.

True time zones are in format `Continent/Region`. Ex: `Europe/Paris` or `Africa/Tunis`. See list in Wikipedia.

To represent a date and time-of-day in the context of a time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`class.

To store a date-time separate from zone, use `LocalDateTime` and `ZoneId` classes.

## Database

Your comments indicate a desire to store the current moment in database.

Capture the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

For use with JDBC 4.2, convert to an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Pass to a prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieve.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Comment: Hi I dont want current moment , instead I want the input date and time with timezone .  InputDate : "03/28/2019 10:00 AM"  , timeZone : America/Los_Angeles                    is it ok if i put like date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a").parse(dateString);
   cal.setTime(date);
   cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(localTimeZone));